# Where can I find a type of beer that comes in flat top beer cans?

Tags: cans

I am looking for a beer that is sold in flat top cans or at least cans that require a tool to open it. A friend and I were discussing it and I thought that it would make an excellent present.

I am not looking for a vintage buy, preferably it should be drinkable.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to track some down myself and their Facebook page is offline and twitter and instagram have not been updated for a year. They might be out of business but I couldn't find any evidence one way or another...

Answer (score 4):

You are in luck! There is a retro can operation called the Chuchkey Beer Co. that is canning beer in the old style flat top cans that you need a churchkey to open (I think they supply one with the case). Looks like it's only available on the West Coast. Enjoy it if you can find it! [Chuchkey Beer Co.](http://www.churchkey.com/home.html)

[image]